# extending flex 4 'group' component problem

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashcatalyst

I have a component that were exported from catalyst (the component is based on a  tag). Now I created a new component extending this. However when I add this new component to my module it doesn't seem to inherit the designs that were exported from catalyst. Any idea how i can do that?

Ofcource when I add the component that were directly out of catalyst all the designs appears..

Thanks.

Comment: ok slight amendment to this question. In the new component I have added a <s:List> with a custom skin. So when i run it all i see is the  List but not any designs from the parent component.

However if I remove the list I see all the designs from the parent. seems like some ordering problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If show you us some code, it may help.  But, it sounds like you're not properly setting the skin class on your List instance.

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't post any code cus the stuff catalyst generated is so long.. any how I have manage to fix it.. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Don't hold us in suspense; what was the issue?